# Windows server 2003 - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Seeing a "Handshake Failure (40)" in wireshark

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-server-2003

**Update: the code works on my desktop so it appears to be an issue with my server**

I am trying to post some XML using vb/asp.net 4.0 via:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(thePostingURL)
```

My code works for many clients, however there is one that I cannot seem to connect to.

I have attempted to research this and things I have tried based on posts I found are:

```
request.KeepAlive = False 

request.KeepAlive = True 

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

Not all at the same time of course. I have tried running Wireshark while posting the XML and it appears to be failing on a "Handshake Failure (40)."

The client's url is https.

Not sure if this is a clue or not, but I cannot access the URL via IE8 while I can using Chrome. This is on a windows 2003 server.

Any ideas or suggestions of things to try?

Comment: I have the exact same problem in a 2003 server client (including the problem in IE) since the server being called was updated from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2. The same 2003 client can connect to a Windows Server 2012 (i.e., not R2).

Comment: @BerendEngelbrecht We updated our server to 2012 and the issue "resolved itself." I assume the older version simply does not support the needed security.